# Fastest way to edit multiple lines of code at the same time

Tags: r, rstudio, multiple-cursor

What is the best way to do the same action across multiple lines of code in the RStudio source editor?

**Example 1**

Let's say that I copy a list from a text file and paste it into R (like the list below). Then, I want to add quotation marks around each word and add a comma to each line, so that I can make a vector.

```
Krista Hicks
Miriam Cummings
Ralph Lamb
Jaylene Gilbert
Jordon Sparks
Kenna Melton
```

*Expected Output*

```
"Krista Hicks",
"Miriam Cummings",
"Ralph Lamb",
"Jaylene Gilbert",
"Jordon Sparks",
"Kenna Melton"
```

**Example 2**

How can I add missing parentheses on multiple lines. For example, if I have an `if` statement, then how can I add the missing opening parentheses for `names` on line 1 and line 4.

```
if (!is.null(names pattern))) {
  vec <- FALSE
  replacement <- unname(pattern)
  pattern[] <- names pattern)
}
```

*Expected Output*

```
if (!is.null(names(pattern))) {
  vec <- FALSE
  replacement <- unname(pattern)
  pattern[] <- names(pattern)
}
```

*Note: These names are just from a random name generator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

RStudio has support for multiple cursors, which allows you to write and edit multiple lines at the same time.

**Example 1**

You can simply click <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows/Linux (or <kbd>option</kbd> on Mac) and drag your mouse to make your selection, or you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to create a rectangular selection from the current location of the cursor to a clicked position.

[image]

---

**Example 2**

Another multiple cursor option is for selecting all matching instances of a term. So, you can select `names` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Then, you can use the arrow keys to move the cursors to delete the space and add in the parentheses.

[image]