# Extract some strings from a copyed list outside r to a character variable

Tags: r, string, special-characters

I am looking for a way to convert specific words from a list outside of R to a character vector of strings.
I need this as I am doing some regex work and the words will be used as filter terms in a data frame.

For instance, let's say I have a series of unquoted words (e.g. If I were to type in the source screen of r-studio):

```
audi
chevrolet
honda
ford
```

I want the above to be turned into:

```
strings = c("audi","chevrolet","honda","ford")
```

As then, I can use it in the following filter:

```
mpg %>% filter(manufacturer %in% strings)
```

The above use is just an example. I'm really looking for a way to turn unquoted text, that has been either entered manually into R or copy-pasted into R, into a comma-separated character vector that can be used for various things. Also, what is the unquoted text that is not a comment in R?

Comment: Have you tried readLines("clipboard"). That should atleast be able to read copied text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_split` from `stringer` is an option too.

You can copy past your string to an r character variable, you can see that `\n`  the Line Feed is you splitting pattern

```r
library(stringr)
st="audi
chevrolet
honda
ford"
cat(st)
#> audi
#> chevrolet
#> honda
#> ford
print(st)
#> [1] "audi\nchevrolet\nhonda\nford"
st2=str_split(st,pattern = "\\n")[[1]]
print(st2)
#> [1] "audi"      "chevrolet" "honda"     "ford"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, so the above is not comma separated right? or is it just that the commas are not shown?

Comment: no it is not a comma separated text, it is just the a copy past from your question between 2 quotes, the line feed character (an ASCII character) moves the cursor down to the next line.

Comment: So to get it to output comma separated what is best approach?

Comment: Or using base `strsplit(st, split = "\n")[[1]]`.

Comment: @Dasr there is no such thing as "comma separated vector". In the question you mentioned the output would be used within `filter`, then this should work fine: `mpg %>% filter(manufacturer %in% st2)`

Comment: if you have a comma separated output ``"name1,name2,name3"`` you have just to change the pattern argument in ``str_split``

Comment: Thanks, I know it would work fine for that specific question. But as mentioned, I was interested in this more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Using *readLines*:

```
strings  <- readLines(con = textConnection("audi
chevrolet
honda
ford"))

strings
#[1] "audi"      "chevrolet" "honda"     "ford"
```

We can also use [RStudio Multiple Cursors](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/productivity/text-editor.html#multiple-cursors), and see related post: [Fastest way to edit multiple lines of code at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71472412/fastest-way-to-edit-multiple-lines-of-code-at-the-same-time)